# Javascript mouseenter event fired twice

Tags: javascript

`.on("mouseenter") and .on("mouseleave")`, 
when console.log the event, in both cases the `event.type` is `"mouseover"`

Is that normal ? I though that for `mouseenter` you see `event.type` `"mouseenter"`

My problem is that javascript mouseenter event fired twice when hovering over the element.

I can see that the event.fromElement is different in both fired events.

How do I stop the bubbling ? `event.stopProppagation`, doesn't work

```
<span class="foo-wrapper">
    <i class="icon-circle"></i>
</span>

 $(".foo-wrapper .icon-circle").on("mouseenter", function(e){ 
   e.stopPropagation();
   cur_target = $(e.target);
   $("#tooltip").css({'top': parseInt(cur_target.offset().top-116), 'left': parseInt(cur_target.offset().left-141)}).fadeIn(150);
 }
```

When the mouse enter the .icon-circle, it fires twice.

Comment: Give us the entire code, including HTML and JS

Comment: try to use return after the code to exit and don't fire again

Comment: Maybe the example at the bottom of this page helps? http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HsLJh/1/ what the problem? For me all works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mouseenter is not a native dom event. Its wrapping mouseover. Let me explain:
Say you have element P, which is 100x100, and that has a child element C which is 50x50.

When you first hover over P, you get both mouseover and mouseenter. When you now hover over C, the browser fires mouseout for P and mouseover for C. 
But C is inside P, so you didn't 'leave' P yet- which is why mouseenter and mouseleave were made.

The library implementing the events checks the targets of the over and out events in order to determine whether to fire enter or leave.

So if its firing twice, its probably from different elements. You need to add the handler to the correct element and not to both.

You can also call event.preventDefault() and/or return false from the event handler.

Comment: It's for the same element, the target is the same, but the 'fromElement' is different

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery v2.1.0 it seems to work properly. Here is an example with your code http://jqversion.com/#!/jad2sKb . It seems that the `mouseenter` event is fired just once, and the `event.type` is `mouseenter`

If there is anything different please update the demo.

Comment: I'm using v1.6.4 and Not thinking of upgrading any time soon

Comment: I think that `.on` method is not available in v1.6.4. You should use `.live` instead. Checkout this updated demo: http://jqversion.com/#!/jad2sKb/1 . It seems it works with `.live()` method